# Rspec testing controller action create logic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

I'm trying to figure out the logic for testing my controller. As you can see in my controller, if a customer is found by phone number, it should render the customer show page, and if a customer is not found by phone number then it should render the create page.

I'm using rspec and factorygirl.

My thought process was to build a test by building a customer, assigning it a specific id: 999999 and phone number.

Then doing a post: create for a customer by using the same phone number. That should have the response return as customers/id.

While my code passes the tests, when I change the post: create customer phone number, it still passes. I don't know what I'm doing wrong, but that it doesn't seem right.

Controller:

```
def create        
   if @customer = Customer.find_by(phone: customer_params[:phone])
     redirect_to @customer
   else
     @customer = Customer.new(customer_params)
     if @customer.save
       redirect_to @customer, notice: "Customer was successfully saved"
     else
       render 'new', notice: "Customer was unsuccessfully saved"
     end
   end
 end
```

Controller Specs #1 (passing):

```
it "redirects to the #show/id path if it is an existing customer" do
   customer = build(:customer)
   customer[:id] = 999999
   customer[:phone] = "999"

   post :create, customer: attributes_for(:customer, phone: "999")            
   expect(response).to redirect_to(:action => :show, :id => assigns(:customer).id)
end
```

Controller Specs #2 (changed the post: create customer phone) ( passing ):

```
it "redirects to the #show/id path if it is an existing customer" do
   customer = build(:customer)
   customer[:id] = 99999
   customer[:phone] = "999"

   post :create, customer: attributes_for(:customer, phone: "939")
   expect(response).to redirect_to(:action => :show, :id => assigns(:customer).id)
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In both cases, when a customer is found or a new customer is created, the `response` will be a `redirect_to` and this is why your tests are passing. Note that since you are using `build` in your test, this is not saving the customer in the database and therefore your test is always creating a new `customer` and `Customer.find_by(phone: customer_params[:phone])` is always evaluating to `nil`.

The best way to test your `create` action is by comparing the count of `Customer` instances before and after the request is made. Here is a how you can improve upon your tests.

```
let(:customer) { FactoryGirl.create(:customer, phone: '999') }

context 'user not found by phone' do
  it 'creates a new customer' do
     expect{
       post :create, customer: attributes_for(:customer, phone: "999")  
     }.to change(Customer, :count).by 1
  end

  it 'redirects to the customer path' do
    post :create, customer: attributes_for(:customer, phone: "999")  

    customer = Customer.last
    expect(response).to redirect_to(customer)

    #this is another differentiator between the case where a customer is 
    #found and when one is created
    expect(flash[:notice).to eq "Customer was successfully saved"
  end
end

context 'user not found by phone' do
  before(:each) do 
    #here we create the customer before each test in this context
    customer
  end

  it 'does not create a new customer' do
     expect{
       post :create, customer: attributes_for(:customer, phone: customer.phone)  
     }.not_to change(Customer, :count)
  end

  it 'redirects to the customer path' do
    post :create, customer: attributes_for(:customer, phone: customer.phone)  

    customer = Customer.last
    expect(response).to redirect_to(customer)

    #this is another differentiator between the case where a customer is 
    #found and when one is created
    expect(flash[:notice).to be_nil
  end
end
```